# Scipy dendrogram leaf node ordering

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to change the ordering of the leaf nodes in the [Scipy dendrogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html) plot function. Consider the following snippet:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, dendrogram
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dists = [ 2., 10.,  3.]
lx = linkage(dists, 'complete')
dendrogram(lx)
plt.show()
```

The resulting dendrogram plot is:

[image: Dendrogram plot]

I would like to change the ordering of the leaf nodes to `0, 1, 2` in this plot. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

I tried all the possible settings of the arguments `count_sort` and `distance_sort` from `dendrogram`, but the ordering remains the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following comment appears in the [source code of the dendrogram scipy method](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/cluster/hierarchy.py#L2417-L2425):

> ```
> # This feature was thought about but never implemented (still useful?):
> #
> #         ... = dendrogram(..., leaves_order=None)
> #
> #         Plots the leaves in the order specified by a vector of
> #         original observation indices. If the vector contains duplicates
> #         or results in a crossing, an exception will be thrown. Passing
> #         None orders leaf nodes based on the order they appear in the
> #         pre-order traversal.
> ```

So this is a relevant question. You can contact the Scipy developers ([SciPy Project Mailing Lists](https://scipy.org/scipylib/mailing-lists.html)) to express your interest in this enhancement so that they become aware that it would be useful and give it more priority.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. The `count_sort` and `distance_sort` options only apply to the descendant nodes.

Imagine your example with the labels 1 and 2 switched. In this case it would be impossible to have the nodes in order as node 1 would need to be forced between the paired nodes 0 and 1. This demonstrates that any process for ordering all the nodes is unscalable.

Comment: I would only be interested to make it work for this particular example (I understand that certain orderings this would not work, but this is not the case)

Comment: I do not think that "This demonstrates that any process for ordering all the nodes is unscalable". It is easy to demonstrate using combinatorics that the linear ordering of the leaves of a non-trivial tree has no single solution. The sorting criteria will determine the precise form of the solution. Iterative or recursive algorithms can do the job.